# Jquery hover list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the function of jquery ".hover". When the mouse is over the #navigation that nothing happens. My code html is:

```
  <ul id="navigation">
<li class="home"><a href="" title="Home"></a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="" title="O nas"></a></li>
<li class="realization"><a href="" title="Realizacje"></a></li>
<li class="devblog"><a href="" title="devBlog"></a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="" title="Kontakt"></a></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation > li').hover(
   function () {
    $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':$('.con').offset().left + $('.con').width()},200);
    alert($('#navigation li').is('.hovered'));
  },
  function () {
    $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'margin-left':  $('.con').offset().left + $('.con').width() - 235}, 200);
    alert($('#navigation li').is('.hovered'));
  }
  );

  $('#navigation a').css('margin-left',  $('.con').offset().left + $('.con').width() - 235  + 'px');
  console.log($('.con').offset().left + $('.con').width() - 235  + 'px');

  alert($('#navigation').is('.hovered'));


});
</script>
```

Anyone know what happens?

There is full code of my site: http://jsfiddle.net/pasterz/cCTgf/

Comment: Did you close the UL ??

Comment: You should be looking into .on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: what's the ".con" element?

Comment: You are selecting something that does not exist on your example's DOM. Calling `.offset()` on it is yielding `undefined`. You cannot get the `left` property of `undefined`. http://jsfiddle.net/6t3yH/

Comment: There is full code of my website: http://jsfiddle.net/pasterz/cCTgf/

Comment: One problem with the code is `alert($('#navigation li').is('.hovered'));` is wrong, it should be `alert($(this).is('.hovered'));`

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
function () {
        $('a', $(this)).stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': 200
        }, 200);
        alert($(this).is(':hover'));
}
```

Make sure the ".con" class exists